# RDS Gateway on non-domain DMZ server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds

Deployment on LAN works without isue.  When I add the Gateway role  to a DMZ workgroup server, there seems to be no way to refer back to the CB on the LAN, though all communication between the two servers is open, and ping, RDP, WMI, etc all function between the two.

All servers are 2012R2, all ports are open for testing. Documentation for this scenario seems to all focus on 2008.

Should this work?

Comment: Can I ask if your internal's rdp farm are configured with ADDS and the  server in the dmz in workgroup ? or it's all in workgroup's model.

Comment: Everything on the LAN is on the domain, it's just the gateway that we're being asked to put out in the DMZ, where everything is (currently) non-AD.

Answer (score 1):

Have you edited the host file with IP and name to the server that contains the CB?Otherwise the DMZ server has no idea where to go when the server isn`t domain joined and have access to DNS records.

Comment: Thanks! It's a good thought, but I should've specified that it's able to resolve LAN hostnames already.